# File not reading properly when running python from cmd

Tags: python

I have my code creating a few files, so I decided I might as well add in the icon too. My idea was to read the file and encode it, so I can store the string to be decoded when the code is run, but that doesn't seem to be working (it appears to be just failing to read the file), and I've no idea why.

This is the test code I'm using:

```
icon = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEAAAABACAYAAACqaXHeAAAV/UlEQVR42s2ZB3gVxdrH95SEhIS0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\n+oJqpgUZBtUekcS22YfmS2I4hn/S/g3X/rLYEq6IggAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==\n' # 
with open('C:/ProgramData/Unified Remote/Remotes/Custom/SteamBasic/icon.png', 'r') as f:
    a = f.read()
    b = a.encode('base64')
    print len(a)
    print len(b)
print b == icon

with open('C:/ProgramData/Unified Remote/Remotes/Custom/SteamBasic/icon2.png', 'w') as f:
    f.write(icon.decode('base64'))
with open('C:/ProgramData/Unified Remote/Remotes/Custom/SteamBasic/icon2.png', 'r') as f:
    print b == f.read().encode('base64')
```

The correct results are these (from running it in Maya):

```
5686
7684
True
True
```

But in my python file I get this from the same block of code:

```
5
9
False
False
```

What's going on? I tried it with a couple of different images, both `base64.b64encode()` and `.encode('base64')` (but obviously that didn't make much difference), and also running cmd as an administrator didn't do anything.

Here's the steam icon I'm using in the example:
[image: steam]

Comment: What's in your file? Start with the first step. There's no reason for `a=f.read()` to read less than the full contents. Why are you seeing `5`? Run it from the console and examine `a`.

Comment: `a` is coming up with something like `ePNG`, so obviously something is wrong there, not sure exactly what to do with it though. `b` is giving out `iVBORwo=`

Comment: What's in your file? It seems the contents of the file are the problem.

Comment: It's the image that I put in the post, even if there's something odd about it, Imgur seems to display it alright, and the python inside Maya managed :P

Comment: Definitely not the image, I just made a random transparent image in Photoshop, saved it to my desktop, and got the same error

Comment: @Peter `r` should be `rb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you open the file with mode 'r', which causes the icon file to be treated as a text file.  Change that 'r' to 'rb' to indicate that you want to treat the file as a binary file.

When the file is read as a text file, the '\x1a' character that occurs in the header of the PNG acts as an end-of-file marker, and therefore the read() returns only the half dozen characters that appear before the '\x1a'.